# Entity Framework with ROWGUIDCOL

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table with a non-PK rowguidcol column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SomeTable] (
  ...
  RowGuid uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID()) ROWGUIDCOL,
  ...
  CONSTRAINT AK_SOMETABLE_ROWGUID UNIQUE (RowGuid)
  ...
 )
```

When I try to add a record through EF (version 4.3.1), the following exception is raised:

```
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'AK_SOMETABLE_ROWGUID'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SomeTable'.
The duplicate key value is (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000).
```

I am leaving the RowGuid field as null. But it seems EF is zeroing out the guid column value.

How do I tell EF that the new row should be populated by NEWSEQUENTIALID() at server level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: After reading this [blog post](http://leedumond.com/blog/using-a-guid-as-an-entitykey-in-entity-framework-4/), I set the StoreGeneratedPattern property to "Identity" in the EDM designer. It seems to be working now.